# Quel est le sens du mot « décaner » au football ?

Tags: québec, régionalismes, sport

Quelqu'un a utilisé le mot **décaner** (ou peut-être **décanner**) dans le sens que le gardien a donné un coup de pied dur au ballon lors d'un match de [football](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/football/34535).

J'ai cherché une définition mais je ne suis pas arrivé à en trouver.

J'ai cherché dans les dictionnaires habituels ([*Trésor*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) et aussi *Le Robert Micro* et le *Multi-Dictionnaire* de Marie-Éva Villiers) et je n'ai trouvé rien.

Sur l'internet j'ai seulement trouvé quelques sites web et liens :

- [Le Dictionnaire vivant de la langue française](http://dvlf.uchicago.edu/mot/d%C3%A9caner)
- [Voir pg.13 «Les règles de sécurité au ballon rotatif: Tu ne dois pas décaner le ballon»](http://www.csrs.qc.ca/fileadmin/user_upload/Ecoles/033-Sylvestre/images/projetcsst/csst.pdf)
- [Twitter 9-MAR-2013 @andreyroysoccer «*Un animateur de #TVASports qui dit "décaner"..... Hmmmmmmm #ImpactTVASports*»](https://twitter.com/andreroysoccer/status/310614354464747520)
- [Twitter 20-JUL-2013 @andreroysoccer «*#ImpactTVASports hmmmmmm, dire décanner.....pas fort pour un animateur*»](https://twitter.com/andreroysoccer/status/358746072933351425)

---

Someone used the word in the sense of the goalie giving the ball a hard kick during a [football](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/football/34535) match.

Although I've searched for a definition I failed to find one.

I searched in the usual dictionaries ([*Trésor*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) and the *Robert-Micro* and Marie-Éva de Villier's *Multi-Dictionnaire*) and found nothing.

I have found only the above links from searching the internet.

Comment: Are you sure the word was really *décaner*? I've never heard that word (but if it's football slang, I wouldn't know). “Dégager le ballon” is a common phrasing and I think (again, not as a football expert) it works the scenario you describe.

Comment: As Gilles, I've never heard "décaner". But I'm not found of football... :)

Comment: +1, jamais entendu le mot "décaner". Mais je ne suis pas non plus un grand fan de football.

Comment: peut-être une extension d'argot + un transitif (tant qu'on y est !): caner : mourir => décaner : faire mourir, et pour un objet, s'en débarrasser, dégager un ballon donc.

Comment: My daughter said it was used when the goalkeeper holds the ball in his/her hands and then kicks it up into the air towards the opposing side. What we would call "clearing" in English I think.  I am also not a football fan :)

Comment: @Micromégas From what you say, I would say "dégager" indeed, which is very common for this situation.

Comment: J'ai trouvé des exemples sur Twitter que j'ai ajouté.  Le même utilisateur a écrit «décaner» et aussi «décanner» par rapport a un jeux de football.

Comment: Je crois bien que les questions portant sur la traduction d'un mot *vers* l'anglais sont off-topic ici. On se spécialise dans la langue française en tant que telle. De ce fait, on peut expliquer ce qu'un mot ou une expression veut dire, mais l'expertise de donner un mot anglais revient à ELU.

Comment: Si la question avait été posée différemment (par exemple, « quel est le sens du mot décaner que j'ai rencontré dans [tel contexte] ») ça aurait fait une bonne question pour FL.

Comment: @laure Je vous remerci de m'aider à poser une meilleure question.

Comment: @guillaume girod-vitouchkina  Théorie interéssante.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax  Bonne précision, C'était à Sherbrooke. Merci pour les liens.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Oui, 5 votes sont nécessaires, ou un vote de modérateur.

Comment: A titre d'anecdote, un Français du Midi ou du Sud-Ouest comprendra probablement naturellement `décaner`... nous avons [décaniller](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_mots_et_expressions_du_Sud-Ouest_de_la_France), régionalisme qui signifie percuter d'un seul tir  !

Comment: Je l'ai entendu cette année provenant d'un enfant de moins de 10 ans des Basses-Laurentides (au nord de Montréal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quelqu'un](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=204298416293465&story_fbid=801948816528419) a identifié une occurrence du verbe *décanner* (dans un [journal étudiant](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:QqmKnkSBW50J:www.lecollectif.ca/mainstream/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca) à Sherbooke, au figuré : « J’vais la décanner comme du monde. ») :

> **Décanner** : Régionalisme [magogois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magog). Frapper un objet (ballon, caillou,
>   etc.) avec le pied.

Le gardien de but a donc *décanné* le ballon, ce que l'enfant qui joue au ballon rotatif en suivant les règles ne devrait pas faire...

---

<sub>*Quelques pistes de réflexion, en partant de la prémisse que décanner<sup>1</sup> est construit sur le verbe **canner** préfixé de dé-* :</sub>

[image: Glossaire du parler français au Canada, 1930]
<sup>[*Glossaire du parler français au Canada*](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf), 1930</sup>

<sub>Avec *canner*, hormis la [préparation](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8875582) de [conserves](https://books.google.com/books?id=4T5AAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=canner%20verbe%20qu%C3%A9bec&source=bl&ots=eZCB4dbU9_&sig=GAaosu-3hPtrbVvGSBC_Zashjp8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKtb-6gajKAhXMlxoKHckMDHMQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=canner%20verbe%20qu%C3%A9bec&f=false) (et le sens d'[annuler](http://www.wikebec.org/canner/definition/) au figuré), on note surtout ***donner des coups de canne*** et la référence aux ***jambes***. On trouvait dans un français [plus ancien](https://archive.org/stream/dictionnairedela01godeuoft#page/776/mode/2up) : « L'autre feri et defoula — Et lui dona une kanee — Qui puis dust estre comparee » (Gilles de Chin, 11<sup>e</sup>). Quant à la référence aux jambes, elle existe encore en argot français (*mettre les [cannes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/canne)*, *casser sa canne* : s'évader ; [décaniller](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9caniller)). La *canne* pouvait aussi valoir [anciennement](https://archive.org/stream/dictionnairehis09conggoog#page/n219/mode/2up) pour une unité de mesure, un roseau (bâton), ou une cruche. Par ailleurs, on trouve au Canada un jeu pour enfants, *kicker la can/canne/[cacanne](https://fr.scoutwiki.org/Kick_la_cacanne)*, une variante du [jeu du loup](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_du_loup) qui implique littéralement de donner un coup de pied à une *boîte de conserve*...</sub>

<sub>En français québécois, *canner une/des balle(s) de golf/de baseball* m'apparaît usuel et familier dans la langue parlée ; ce sont deux sports qui se pratiquent avec une canne/un bâton. Je n'ai pas de difficulté à étendre l'idée à une *rondelle* ou même à un *ballon*, même sans canne dans ce dernier cas ; il s'agit d'envoyer au loin avec *un coup puissant*, à l'aide d'un bâton, avec les pieds. Le préfixe du verbe *décanner* des Cantons-de-l'Est, sert peut-être à marquer l'[éloignement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9-/2) (frapper l'objet *loin*) ou l'[intensité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9-/1) (frapper l'objet *fort*). C'est non sans rappeler aussi, quoique différemment, d'autres verbes comme *décocher* ou *dégager*, où on laisse aller ce qui était retenu (la flèche, le trait, le tir, le bien etc.). Ça m'a aussi fait penser à *décamper* quand on lève le camp. Incidemment, pour compléter sur cette lancée, voir [*garrocher*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/garrocher) ([*FEW*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/lire/62/177)), et [*garnotte*](http://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/garrocher-de-la-garnotte/)(r) ([2](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/garnotte)).</sub>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Je prononce *décanner* /dekane/, mais *canner* /'ka<sup>a</sup>ne/ (*k* explosif, et le *a* est long, comme si diphtongué ; similaire à l'anglais *can*, + *é*).</sub>

Comment: Nice! Regarding & similar to the “annuler” notion is the slang use of “can” in Eng to mean “to fire"=“virer”=“renvoyer,” which also has some formal Fr meanings involving sports/balls; but that’s probably too tenuous, as it requires first moving from slang Eng (can) to slang Fr (virer); then from Fr slang (virer) to formal Fr (renvoyer); & finally to a use in Fr that doesn’t even exist in Eng (not to mention that it doesn’t explain the addition of the “dé”)! Re “dé,” if “can” could mean “cover[ing]” then to “uncan” (décanner) a ball could mean to kick it so hard that you “kicked its cover off.”

Answer (score 5):

En argot, les *cannes*, ce sont les jambes.

*Décaner* (l'orthographe ne compte pas, seule la phonétique compte) est donc se servir des cannes (des jambes, très souvent du pied) pour dégager, éloigner un objet.

***dé***[*gager* un ballon avec une]***cane(r)*** : shooter ou dégager un ballon au pied.

Pour certains jeux, on peut utiliser le genou, voire la cuisse.

Notons aussi que le paronyme *déconner* procède de la même logique, sortir des règles sociales et des bons usages en agissant comme un *con*.
(N.B. : les mots *en italiques* sont familiers, très courants, mais à réserver à l'oral entre amis).

Answer (score 1):

En anglais, un dégagement est une `clearance` les options suivantes existent

> Clear the ball.
>
> Clear the box or goal.

Et du fait que le gardien a l'option d'utiliser ses pieds et ses mains, il est possible de preciser que le gardien dégage la balle au pied avec

> He booted it

Comment: Existe-t-il le mot «décaner» dans ce sens?

Comment: Jamais entendu le mot "décaner" personnellement, j'ai juste proposé l'anglais pour la définition fournise: "dans le sens que le gardien a donné un coup de pied dur au ballon lors d'un match de football"

Answer (score 1):

A community member who happens to be a native English speaker commented *to can* can be slang for "to fire s.o."; there might or might not be an idea of motion involved here. Nevertheless, the reason why the English language might be relevant here is because the *Eastern Townships* (see [*Estrie*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrie)) where the events described in the question unfolded, have an influence/heritage from the original English-speaking settlers from *New England* (U.S.).

And this allows for the possibility that the source for the verb might be different from an extension of the *stick/legs* meaning. One can speculate because of the phonetics of the sentence *kick the can*, if there were an ellipsis of the verb, you'd be left with **/dəkan/**, which could then simply be adapted to French i.e. verbed (+r); the *dé-* prefix (i.e. using /e/ instead of /ə/ in context) is natural as *de-* doesn't even seem to be a prefix at all. If that were true, and considering the history this is certainly possible, then the verb *décanner* would not constitute an extension of the *canner* usage picked up in *South Western Québec French* as discussed [elsewhere](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17412): it would be an independent adaptation to regional French from casual English where the verb was dropped:

> (kick) *the can* = /dəkan/(n.) ⇒ /dekane/(v.)... to kick something/frapper, donner un coup de pied sur.

---

Vu l'influence de la langue anglaise dans la région de l'[Estrie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrie), vu son l'histoire, il est possible qu'il s'agisse d'une transformation appliquée à la prononciation anglaise de *the can* dans un truc comme *to kick the can* ; il y aurait eu ellipse du verbe et on parlerait à l'origine de donner un coup de pied, de frapper, une *boîte de conserve* comme tel. On peut spéculer que du nom on aurait fait un verbe (prononcé sur le modèle *-er*), puis on l'aurait adapté vu que le préfixe naturel est *dé-* et non pas *de-*. Si ça s'avérait<sup>1</sup> être le cas, ce serait indépendant d'une extension du sens de *canner* tel qu'on l'entendrait dans le [sud-ouest](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17412) du Québec, et ce serait donc une adaptation française régionale d'un segment de phrase en langue anglaise.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Si quelqu'un fait de la recherche sur le sujet des régionalismes en français québécois ou si on a d'autres informations sur l'origine de ce verbe en Estrie, on pourra aisément modifier cette réponse.</sub>

Comment: Another _very_ tenuous link might be with the (U.K.) use of the phrase "to cane it" which can mean either to be under the influence of some drug, or else to do something with great speed or power.  http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cane-it   or for an example of use (in the game of cricket) http://www.espncricinfo.com/the-ashes-2013/content/story/663879.html  _"milepost on August 22, 2013, 7:31 GMT @Jared Hansen, he didn't 'not walk'. He **caned it** to slip, like chipping it back to the bowler."_

Comment: @Micromégas Thanks! I don't think any of this is tenuous. I believe the scenario in the community wiki is actually the most likely one, but it need not be either or. I found all of this meshes. I just don't have the expertise to analyze how English would have impacted this differently in Sherbrooke than in Montreal, if at all. As we don't know when _décanner_ was first attested and ngram of course doesn't have a corpus which would showcase any of this, it's hard to speculate on the influences etc. With time further research can increment this. Thanks again, that was an interesting Q. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Coup de pied de dégagement, botté;  en anglais "to punt ".
Utiliser ses cannes (jambes) pour éloigner le ballon au soccer (football européen).
Régionalisme utilisé en Estrie /  Cantons de l'est
"Kicker" un ballon haut, fort et loin. Pas nécessairement, mais habituellement utilisé par le gardien de but. Utilisé aussi lorsque le jeune a frappé le ballon trop fort...
En cours de récré : "Interdit de décanner le ballon"  ou "il a décanné le ballon sur le toit", " Décannes ! Décannes ! "lorsque les attaquants arrivent ou s'activent autour du ballon.